# iOS : adding zposition and button action doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I have implement a walkthroughs in beginning of my app and a button in last walkthroughs view for going to another view controller but I didn't see the button so I searched and add this statement

```
    self.mybutton.layer.zposition = 1
```

so finally after this code I see my button but the action for my doesn't work anymore ??

thanks for any help

Comment: dont use the `zposition` alternate use bringsubviewtofront

Comment: I test that doest work for me

Comment: may be the problem occurs because of wrong constraints. I

Comment: when I go in debug view hierarchy I see there are 4 view are in front of my button

Comment: This is only affective for the button's superview.  Thus if there is another view on top of the button's superview, you will still not see the button.

Comment: I see button but I don't know why it dose'nt work it is custom library that I'm using of walkthrough this really weird to me

Answer (score 2):

Move your button to on top of all other views in  story board and then check

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: yourBtn)
```

Comment: You were saying you had 4 views on top of that button.. Thats y i asked you this. keep searching :(

Comment: I said in debug view hierarchy and I add them by code not drag and drop  in story board to see them :(

Comment: Try the code above by putting it in view did load method.

Comment: unwrapping error and I try to add it to view didappear and nothing happened      https://github.com/Mahdimm/TShop  if it is able for go and check it maybe you don't understand me completely

Answer (score 1):

Use `bringSubviewToFront` instead of `zposition`

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.mybutton];
```

Comment: which library is you using?

Comment: https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding    this is the library                     https://github.com/Mahdimm/TShop this my app that I have implement it